# How to upload an image in Elgg

Tags: php, file-upload, elgg

I have been trying to save an **Elgg** entity icon in **Elgg 3.x** but to no success. **`myObject`** saves into the database, but the file doesn't get uploaded.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

**save.php form**

```
<?php
    echo elgg_view('input/file', [
        'name' => 'upload[]',
        'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'picTuREs',
    ]);
?>
```

**save.php action file**

```
foreach (elgg_get_uploaded_files('upload') as $upload)
{
    $myObject = new ElggObject();
    $myObject->subtype = "my_object";
    $myObject->access_id = ACCESS_PUBLIC;

    $myObject->saveIconFromUploadedFile($upload);

    $myObject->save();
}
```

Comment: Have you error reporting enabled?

Comment: Yes I do have it enabled from plugins Elgg Developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Update your action on this:

```
$upload_guids = (array) get_input('uploads');

if (empty($upload_guids)) {
    return elgg_error_response(elgg_echo('file:error:empty_form'));
}

foreach ($upload_guids as $upload_guid) {
    $file = new \ElggFile();
    
    $file->title = $title;
    $file->description = $description;
    $file->access_id = $access_id;
    $file->container_guid = $container_guid;
    $file->tags = string_to_tag_array($tags);

    $file->save();
    
    if ($file->getSimpleType() === 'image') {
        $file->saveIconFromElggFile($file);
    }
}
```

If you use a custom subtype then you should extend `\ElggFile` via this object something like this:

```
class MyCustomFile extends \ElggFile {
    
    const SUBTYPE = 'my_subtype';
    
    protected function initializeAttributes() {
        parent::initializeAttributes();

        $this->attributes['subtype'] = self::SUBTYPE;
    }
    
    /**
     * @see ElggEntity::saveIconFromElggFile()
     */
    public function saveIconFromElggFile(\ElggFile $file, $type = 'icon', array $coords = array()) {
        return false;
    }
}
```